# How to pass multiple parameters in post request in karate framework?

Tags: api, karate

I have a JSON data file which has data like

```
{
  "Status": "Pending",
  "role": "manager",
  "client": "android",
  "user": "test@abc.com",
  "eTyres":
  {
    "Wheels": {
      "title": "Alloy Wheel",
      "value": "Yes"
    }
 }
}
```

Firstly, I want to read this data and *when Wheels.value == Yes* then I want to hit an API else hit another API
Also, I would like to know how i can pass multiple parameters in post request or from the file.

**Post request data is as follows:**

```
title:Alloy_wheel__Info
part:acCooling
partTitle:AC Cooling
partValue:No
```

> Above data i'm passing through "form-data" in postman.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is hard to understand and I will assume that you want to loop over some given JSON array and do some actions. Sounds like you are not "testing" and mis-using Karate !

To loop over a JSON array, use `call`. Refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features

To do conditionals, read this part of the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

To do "form-data" read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#form-field

```
* def data = { "Status": "Pending", "role": "manager", "client": "android", "user": "test@abc.com", "eTyres": { "Wheels": { "title": "Alloy Wheel", "value": "Yes" } } }
* eval data.eTyres.Wheels.value == 'Yes' ? karate.call('api1.feature') : karate.call('api2.feature')
```

How to implement `api1.feature` and `api2.feature` is a homework for you. Keep in mind that in both you will still have access to the `data` variable. And please read the docs and examples !

Comment: Yes, i want to read data from json and then decide which api to hit.

Comment: used same statement but getting error as : <eval>:1:126 Expected ; but found else

Comment: @Sanchit sorry - I made a mistake. if you read the docs you would have figured out. edited my answer